Question about home directory permissions script
When setting Azure policy on a Linux VM, Microsoft uses the OMS agent to configure everything, in particular, the omsremediate command.  Looking through their GitHub site for the OMS agent for Linux, I found their oms_audit.xml file, which lists audit findings and remediations for various policy items (https://github.com/Microsoft/OMS-Agent-for-Linux/blob/master/source/code/plugins/oms_audits.xml).  Audit finding #28 (fix-home-dir-permissions) states that home directory permissions should be set to 750 or more restrictive.  Looking at the remediation for this further down in the file, MS provides this script snippet to fix the problem:
chmod 750 /home/*
if [ -e /var/lib/libuuid ]; then
    chmod 750 /var/lib/libuuid
fi
chmod 750 /var/run/dbus
chmod 750 /var/run/dbus
# /var/run/sshd created by service at bootup
if [ -e /etc/init.d/ssh ]; then
  sed -i 's/\(chmod\s\+\)[0-7]\{4\}/\10750/g' /etc/init.d/ssh
fi
if [ -e /etc/init.d/sshd ]; then
  sed -i 's/\(chmod\s\+\)[0-7]\{4\}/\10750/g' /etc/init.d/sshd
fi
if [ -e /etc/init/ssh.conf ]; then
  sed -i 's/\(mkdir\s\+-p\s\+-m\)[0-9]\{4\}/\10750/g' /etc/init/ssh.conf
fi

The first line, I understand.  It's setting everything under /home to 750.  But what about the next several lines?  Is this an error or is there a reason to be changing permissions on /var/lib/libuuid, /var/run/dbus, /etc/init.d/ssh, /etc/init.d/sshd, and /etc/init/ssh.conf?  I'm trying to figure out if those lines in the snippet belong under the "fix home dir permissions" section or if they should be somewhere else?  I'm trying to translate an existing script that makes extensive use of omsremediate into a script that simply uses native Linux commands, depending on the distro.  Anyone have any insight as to why these additional lines would fall under the "fix home dir permissions" section?

/etc/init.d/ssh uses chmod in function check_privsep_dir(), which creates the PrivSep empty directory if it's missing.  This is related to logins, like the other three changes that you show; it's not specific to home directories.
I'd categorize everything other than the /home change into one or more different categories.
You may want to review other frameworks, such as the CIS Benchmarks List, for ideas about how best to organize such changes.
